# Solutions $u(t)$ and $v(t)$ of $x'=Ax$ such that every solution is a linear combination of $u(t)$ and $v(t)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

For 
$$A=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & -2   \end{pmatrix}$$

Find solutions $u(t)$ and $v(t)$ of $x'=Ax$ such that every solution is a linear combination of $u(t)$ and $v(t)$.

I've found the solution $x(t)=(c_1 e^t,c_2 e^{-2t})$, for some $c_i$ real constants.

I don't know where to go from here.

Comment: You're done, basically. Your $x$ consists of all solutions. You have two parameters. So...

Comment: so I can give any value for c1 and c2? to find a particular solution

Comment: Yes, you get particular solutions by fixing those two parameters. So pick two pairs of two parameters so that the solutions are not linearly dependent.

Comment: (0,1) and (1,0) and then I have (e^t,0) and (0,e^-2t)

Comment: Yup! Sounds good to me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let  $u (t)=(e^t, 0) $ and $v (t)=(0, e^ {-2t}) $.  Then the general solution you have found is a linear combination of  $u $ and $v $, which are themselves solutions...

Comment: Should the final answer be $u(t)=(c_1e^t,0)$ and $v(t)=(0,c_2e^{-2t})$? Because I think yours is a particular solution and the exercise asks for solutions $u(t)$ and $v(t)$ of $x'=Ax$ such that  every solution is a linear combination of $u(t)$ and $v(t).$

Comment: Every solution is a linear combination of $(e^t,0)$ and $(0,e^{-2t})$.  A linear combination of $u(t)$ and $v(t)$ is anything of the form $c_1u(t)+c_2v(t)$.  So we're good.

Comment: :) I see, a little bit late but thanks!

Comment: Better late than never!